# Can I use webhook data for telegram response in API.ai?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, dialogflow-es

We created a simple telegram bot with API.ai integration.
When I ask smth it make a webhook to my server and respond with some text.
But I want to enrich my response with image and maybe some other things.
This functionality available in telegram tab only.

But I can't access webhook data in telegram custom response.
How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

API.AI has two ways to send a response to Telegram custom responses that contain rich messages (like cards and images).

1. **Define your response in API.AI's console**

Click the [image] button in the response section of your intent and select Telegram:
[image]
Then click on "Add message content" to add different types of rich messages to Telegram:
[image]
Then fill out the rich response with the data you'd like to respond with.  Here is a link to the documentation for more info: https://api.ai/docs/rich-messages

2. **Define your response in API.AI's fulfillment webhook**
   You can also define dynamic responses in your webhook. To define Telegram specific responses include the following JSON in your responses to API.AI webhook requests.  For example...

   {
     "data": {
       "telegram": {
         "reply_markup": {
           "inline_keyboard": [
             [
               {
                 "callback_data": "Red",
                 "text": "Red"
               }
             ],
             [
               {
                 "callback_data": "Green",
                 "text": "Green"
               }
             ],
             [
               {
                 "callback_data": "Yellow",
                 "text": "Yellow"
               }
             ],
             [
               {
                 "callback_data": "Blue",
                 "text": "Blue"
               }
             ],
             [
               {
                 "callback_data": "Pink",
                 "text": "Pink"
               }
             ]
           ]
         },
         "text": "Pick a color"
       }
     }
     ...
   }

The above JSON response would create a Telegram inline keyboard response with 5 options (Red/Green/Blue/Yellow/Pink).  The documentation is here: https://api.ai/docs/rich-messages#custom-payload